# How to create a custom async function in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

In JS, I can create promise returning function as,

```
function asyncFn() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    // Resolve after some tasks are completed
    resolve(true)
  })
}
```

Afterwards I can do,

```
async function sign() {
  await asyncFn()
  console.log("asyncFn() completed")
}
```

or in swift way,

```
func sign() async {
  let _ = await asyncFn()
  print("asyncFn() completed")
}
```

This is just an example. Basically I want some tasks to finish and then resolve the promise/future.

How do I do the same with Swift? Swift 5.5 supports async/await so is there a way to create own custom async or promise returning function?

Comment: I don't understand; Does the timeout represent the failure case?  If so then you need to pick an appropriate value to give the task time to complete and after which it is considered to have failed.

Comment: @Paulw11 No the timer doesn't have a failure case. The timer was just an example. I just want to return a Promise/Future in a function resolved after an unknown period of time.

Comment: So just use the new Async/await in Swift 5.5.  A function marked `async` effectively returns a promise, but because it's a first class language feature you don't need to wrap the result in a promise explicitly.

Comment: I’d suggest watching various async/await WWDC videos (e.g., [Meet async/await](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10132)).

Comment: I suspect there is some aspect to your question that we must not be understanding. If that is the case, perhaps you can edit your question to clarify. In your question, you include Swift async/await example and then later ask “how do you do the same in Swift?” You just did it in Swift, a few lines above…

Answer (score -2):

recommend to read [this](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html)

```
func delayFetchNames() async -> [String] {
    await Task.sleep(2 * 1_000_000_000)  // Two seconds
    return ["IMG001", "IMG002"]
}
await delayFetchNames()
```

Comment: This is not reliable though. What I showed in my question was just an example. There will obviously be conditions where you don't know the exact amount of delay. I will update my question.

Comment: What's your question then? This answer is obviously an example too: The delay represents a call of an arbitrary asynchronous function.